# Loop through a list of folders to delete old ones

Tags: ansible

I want to implement some sort of rotation on subdirectories of folders in a list. Say I have *dir1* and *dir2*, I need to go inside each of them and delete all folders older than `X` days in *dir1* and `Y` days in *dir2*.

```yaml
vars:
  backups:
    dir1:
      name: dir1
      days: 10d
    dir2:
      name: dir2
      days: 3d
```

I've tried to create a task like this

```yaml
- name: find all folders
  find:
    paths: "/home/user1/{{ item.value.name }}"
    age: "{{ item.value.days }}"
    file_type: directory
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', backups) }}"
  register: dirsOlderThanXd
```

But, `dirsOlderThanXd` has a strange format. If there were no loop and just a single directory next step would be something like

```yaml
- name: remove old folders
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ dirsOlderThanXd.files }}"
```

Documentation says

> When you use `register` with a loop, the data structure placed in the variable will contain a `results` attribute that is a list of all responses from the module. This differs from the data structure returned when using `register` without a loop.

So, it's expected, but, how exactly do I work with this output? Or am I doing it all completely wrong?

Comment: You're doing it right. See the list ``dirsOlderThanXd.results``.  This is the ``list of all responses from the module``. If you have a problem [edit] the question and make it [mre]. See also [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

You can access the list — `results` — of list — `files` — using a [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) filter, then [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) the resulting list of list:

```yaml
- name: remove old folders
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ dirsOlderThanXd.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

---

Given the two tasks:

```yaml
- name: find all folders
  find:
    paths: "/home/user1/{{ item.value.name }}"
    age: "{{ item.value.days }}"
    file_type: directory
  loop: "{{ backups | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"
  register: dirsOlderThanXd  
  vars:
    backups:
      dir1:
        name: dir1
        days: 10d
      dir2:
        name: dir2
        days: 3d

- name: remove old folders
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}" 
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ dirsOlderThanXd.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

This would yields something along the line of:

```
TASK [find all folders] **************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=dir1)
ok: [localhost] => (item=dir2)

TASK [remove old folders] ************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user1/dir1/foo)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user1/dir1/bar)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user1/dir2/qux)
changed: [localhost] => (item=/home/user1/dir2/baz)
```